# Errors on build in a file that doesn't exists anymore/was renamed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, t4

[image]

I have a few t4 templates in my solution and at some point I renamed the the files and made some changes to them. When I did a build I got the above errors. Interestingly enough when I click on the file names nothing happens and when I hover over them to get the full name I notice that it's referencing the file name that I changed earlier. Also I've gone to all the files it could possibly be referencing and made sure that this error is not occurring in any of them.

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding, ensuring that all the projects are configured to build in the configuration manager. I deleted the file that I renamed and recreated it and the errors were still present *even while the file was delete*. Also I tried creating a file with the exact same name as the one referenced in the error message and it actually let me create the file, indicating that vs clearly knows that there is not file with that name so it seems to be a problem specifically with the debugger maybe?

I suspect this could be some strange behaviour with t4 templates as I feel like something like this happened before. A full restart of my machine was what solved that last time but it didn't work this time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after hours of unsuccessfully scouring the internet I noticed that the 'CustomTool' field in the file properties had a typo in it which was causing the strange error.